# unprocessedResponseCount < 0 on decrement. Disabling connection resiliency. java

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, prepared-statement

Early I faced with a problem **"unprocessedResponseCount < 0 on decrement. Disabling connection resiliency.java"** After some time of searching a problem, I didn't find anything about it.
When the problem is appear:

- use batch for save data from java application
- use MSSQL server as a DB
- use MSSQL driver 12.1.0.jre11-preview

Comment: I came across scant information. This mistake was appear in driver for MSSQL. And I fix it by add new dependency on my project. I added 12.4.2.jre11.